# webmethods package dependency

Tags: dependencies, webmethods

I'd like to collect the dependencies of specific packages of the webmethods integration server, with a separate java program, outside the designer.

Where are these dependencies stored in the file system ?

thank you

Answer (score 4):

Package dependencies that are declared at the package level are stored in the package manifest file: `IntegrationServer/packages/<packageName>/manifest.v3`.

For example, the [manifest](https://github.com/Permafrost/Tundra/blob/master/manifest.v3) file in the [Tundra](https://github.com/Permafrost/Tundra) package includes a `<record name="requires"...>` element that lists the three packages it depends on (WmFlatFile, WmPublic, and WmRoot):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Values version="2.0">
  <value name="enabled">yes</value>
  <value name="system_package">no</value>
  <value name="version">0.0.13</value>
  <record name="startup_services" javaclass="com.wm.util.Values">
    <null name="tundra.support:access"/>
  </record>
  <null name="shutdown_services"/>
  <null name="replication_services"/>
  <record name="requires" javaclass="com.wm.util.Values">
    <value name="WmFlatFile">*.*</value>
    <value name="WmPublic">*.*</value>
    <value name="WmRoot">*.*</value>
  </record>
  <value name="listACL">Default</value>
  <value name="description">A package of cool services for webMethods Integration Server 7.1 or higher</value>
  <value name="publisher">Lachlan Dowding &lt;lachlan@permafro.st&gt;</value>
  <value name="webappLoad">yes</value>
</Values>
```

The easiest way to parse this XML is to use the `com.wm.util.coder.IDataXMLCoder` object from the webMethods Integration Server client JAR `wm-isclient.jar`. Here's a quick example:

```java
public static String[] getDependencies(String packageName) throws java.io.IOException {
  String filename = ".../IntegrationServer/packages/" + packageName + "/manifest.v3";
  java.io.InputStream in = null;

  try {
    in = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(new java.io.FileInputStream(filename));
    com.wm.util.coder.XMLCoderWrapper codec = new com.wm.util.coder.XMLCoderWrapper();
    com.wm.data.IData manifestDocument = codec.decode(in);

    com.wm.data.IDataCursor manifestCursor = manifestDocument.getCursor();
    com.wm.data.IData requiresDocument = com.wm.data.IDataUtil.getIData(manifestCursor, "requires");
    manifestCursor.destroy();

    java.util.List<String> dependencies = new java.util.ArrayList<String>();
    if (requiresDocument != null) {
      com.wm.data.IDataCursor requiresCursor = requiresDocument.getCursor();

      while(requiresCursor.next()) {
        String dependency = requiresCursor.getKey();
        String version = (String)requiresCursor.getValue();

        dependencies.add(dependency);
      }
      requiresCursor.destroy();
    }

    return dependencies.toArray(new String[dependencies.size()]);
  } finally {
    if (in != null) in.close();
  }
}
```

---

If package dependencies are not declared in the package manifest, you can calculate them by checking the references of every service within the package using code similar to the following method culled from [Tundra.java](https://github.com/Permafrost/Tundra.java/blob/ec863c8e785fdee8e1d9fd368cde5dac6518a5c9/src/main/java/permafrost/tundra/server/PackageHelper.java#L151):

```java
import com.wm.app.b2b.server.ns.NSDependencyManager;
import com.wm.app.b2b.server.Package;
import com.wm.app.b2b.server.ns.Namespace;
import com.wm.data.IData;
import com.wm.data.IDataCursor;
import com.wm.data.IDataFactory;
import com.wm.data.IDataUtil;
import com.wm.lang.ns.DependencyManager;
import com.wm.lang.ns.NSNode;
import com.wm.lang.ns.NSService;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;

...

/**
 * Returns the list of services that are dependent on the services in the given package.
 *
 * @param packageName   The package to get dependents for.
 * @return              The list of dependents for the given package.
 */
private static IData getDependents(String packageName) {
    return getDependents(getPackage(packageName));
}

/**
 * Returns the list of services that are dependent on the services in the given package.
 *
 * @param pkg           The package to get dependents for.
 * @return              The list of dependents for the given package.
 */
private static IData getDependents(Package pkg) {
    DependencyManager manager = NSDependencyManager.current();
    Namespace namespace = Namespace.current();

    SortedSet<String> packages = new TreeSet<String>();
    SortedMap<String, IData> nodes = new TreeMap<String, IData>();

    Enumeration services = pkg.getLoaded();
    while(services.hasMoreElements()) {
        String service = (String)services.nextElement();
        if (service != null) {
            NSNode node = namespace.getNode(service);
            if (node != null) {
                IData results = manager.getDependent(node, null);
                if (results != null) {
                    IDataCursor resultsCursor = results.getCursor();
                    IData[] referencedBy = IDataUtil.getIDataArray(resultsCursor, "referencedBy");
                    resultsCursor.destroy();
                    if (referencedBy != null) {
                        for (IData dependent : referencedBy) {
                            if (dependent != null) {
                                IDataCursor dependentCursor = dependent.getCursor();
                                String name = IDataUtil.getString(dependentCursor, "name");
                                dependentCursor.destroy();

                                String[] parts = name.split("\\/");

                                if (parts.length > 1) {
                                    if (!pkg.getName().equals(parts[0])) {
                                        IData result = IDataFactory.create();
                                        IDataCursor resultCursor = result.getCursor();
                                        IDataUtil.put(resultCursor, "package", parts[0]);
                                        IDataUtil.put(resultCursor, "node", parts[1]);
                                        resultCursor.destroy();

                                        packages.add(parts[0]);
                                        nodes.put(name, result);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    IData output = IDataFactory.create();
    IDataCursor cursor = output.getCursor();
    IDataUtil.put(cursor, "packages", packages.toArray(new String[packages.size()]));
    IDataUtil.put(cursor, "packages.length", packages.size());
    IDataUtil.put(cursor, "nodes", nodes.values().toArray(new IData[nodes.size()]));
    IDataUtil.put(cursor, "nodes.length", nodes.size());
    cursor.destroy();

    return output;
}
```

Comment: What if the manifest file doesn't have this kind of information ?

Comment: Now I'm interested in every idea considering how to find out the dependencies of a packes :)

Comment: You need to use the undocumented API.

Comment: @Webtkl I have added an example of the Java code needed to calculate package dependencies manually, regardless of whether the package manifest file declares the dependencies or not.